# How can a process handle multiple requests on a web server using sockets?TCP

Tags: multithreading, sockets, tcp, process, port

I know that you utilize a port to address a process and that you have to use sockets for handling multiple requests on web server, but how does it work? Is the process creating multiple socket threads for each connection? Is threading the answer?

Answer (score 2):

**Overview**

This is a great question, and one that will take a bit to explain fully. I will step through different parts of this topic below. I personally learned multi-threading in Java, which has quite an extensive concurrency library. Although my examples will be in Java, the concepts will stand between languages.

**Is threading valid?**

In short, yes this is a perfect use case for multi-threading, although single-threaded is fine for simple scenarios as well. However, there does exist better designs that may yield better performance and safer code. The great thing is there are loads of examples on how to do this on the internet!

---

**Multi-Threading**

Lets investigate sample code from [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introducing-threads-socket-programming-java/), seen below.

```
public class Server 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // server is listening on port 5056
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5056);

        // running infinite loop for getting
        // client request
        while (true) 
        {
            Socket s = null;

            try
            {
                // socket object to receive incoming client requests
                s = ss.accept();

                System.out.println("A new client is connected : " + s);

                // obtaining input and out streams
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

                System.out.println("Assigning new thread for this client");

                // create a new thread object
                Thread t = new ClientHandler(s, dis, dos);

                // Invoking the start() method
                t.start();

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                s.close();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Server code is actually quite basic but still does the job well. Lets step through all the logic seen here:

1. The Server sets up on Socket 5056
2. The Server begins its infinite loop
3. The client *blocks* on `ss.accept()` until a client request is received on part 5056
4. The Server does relatively minimal operations (i.e. `System.out` logging, set up IO streams)
5. A `Thread` is **created** and **assigned** to this request
6. The `Thread` is started
7. The loop repeats

The mentality here is that the server acts as a dispatcher. Requests enter the server, and the server allocates workers (`Threads`) to complete the operations in parallel so that the server can wait for and assist the next, incoming request.

**Pros**

1. Simple, readable code
2. Operations in parallel allows for increased performance with proper synchronization

**Cons**

1. The dangers of multi-threading
2. The creation of threads is quite cumbersome and resource intensive, thus should not be a frequent operation
3. No re-use of threads
4. Must manually limit threads

---

**Thread Pool**

Lets investigate sample code from [this article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/thread-pooled-server.html), seen below.

```
while(! isStopped()){
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if(isStopped()) {
            System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
            break;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Error accepting client connection", e);
    }
    this.threadPool.execute(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket,"Thread Pooled Server"));
}
```

Note, I excluded the setup because it is rather similar to the Multi-Threaded example. Lets step through the logic in this example.

1. The server waits for a request to arrive on its alloted port
2. The server sends the request to a handler that is given to the `ThreadPool` to run
3. The `ThreadPool` receives `Runnable` code, allocated a worker, and begin code execution in parallel
4. The loop repeats

The server again acts as a dispatcher; it listens for the request, receives one, and ships it to a `ThreadPool`. The `ThreadPool` abstracts the complex resource management from the developer and executes the code optimized fully. This is very similar to the multi-thread example, but all resource management is packaged into the `ThreadPool`. The code is reduced further from the above example, and it is much safer for non-multi-threading professionals. Note, the `WorkerRunnable` is only a `Runnable`, not a raw `Thread`, whilst the `ClientHandler` in the Multi-Thread example was a raw `Thread`.

**Pros**

1. Threads are managed and re-used by the pool
2. Further simplify code base
3. Inherits all benefits from the Multi-Threaded example

**Cons**

1. There is a learning curve to fully understanding pooling and different configurations of them

---

**Notes**

In Java, there exists another implementation called [RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html), that attempts to abstract away the *network*, thus allowing the communication of Client-Server to happen as though it is on one JVM, even if it is on many. Although this as well can use multi-threading, it is another approach to the issue instead of sockets.

Comment: Why create 'dis' and 'dos' in the accept() loop instead of in the client<>server handler thread once it gets its 's'?

Comment: I kept that in to keep the integrity of the example. It has no effect on the example. Most likely it would be better to put that in the handler thread. If you want, I can update the code and remove it if it is causing confusion